Parsing videoUrl from one page to another in React
I would like to parse the videoUrl so that when I click the 'Watch Video' link in the table, allowing the video to be displayed on a different page when it loads using React.
I used the Link, useParams from React-Router-DOM but the video does not get displayed when I get redirected to the watch video page. The video URL is working fine when I take it from my database and paste it in the browser.
This is my two pages for reference:
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Table, TableBody, TableCell, TableContainer, TableHead, TableRow, Paper } from `your text`'@mui/material';
import axios from 'axios';

`const ListVideos = () => {
  const [videos, setVideos] = useState([]);
  const [distinctAssignments, setDistinctAssignments] = useState([]);
  const [selectedAssignment, setSelectedAssignment] = useState('');
  const [visibleCount, setVisibleCount] = useState(3);
  const [showMore, setShowMore] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState('');

  // Fetch videos from the API
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchVideos = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/video-submissions');
        setVideos(response.data);

        // Extract distinct assignment names after fetching videos
        const uniqueAssignments = [...new Set(response.data.map(video => video.assign_name))];
        setDistinctAssignments(uniqueAssignments);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching videos:', error);
        setError('Failed to load videos. Please try again later.');
      }
    };

    fetchVideos();
  }, []);

  const toggleShowMore = () => {
    setShowMore(!showMore);
    setVisibleCount(showMore ? 3 : videos.length);
  };

  // Filter videos by selected assignment name
  const filteredVideos = videos.filter(video =>
    selectedAssignment ? video.assign_name === selectedAssignment : true
  );

  return (
    <div className="page">
      <header>
        <div className="container">
          <h1 className="page-heading">List of Video Submissions</h1>
          <ul className="linksList">
            <li>
              <Link to="/" className="link">Landing Page</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/watch-feedback/:id" className="link">Watch Video</Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </header>

      <div className="page-Container">
        <div className="assignment-container">
          <label htmlFor="assignment">Filter by Assignment Name:</label>
          <select
            value={selectedAssignment}
            onChange={(e) => setSelectedAssignment(e.target.value)}
            aria-label="Select Assignment"
            style={{ marginBottom: '10px', padding: '8px', width: '100%' }}
          >
            <option value="">Select an assignment...</option>
            {distinctAssignments.length > 0 ? (
              distinctAssignments.map((assignment, index) => (
                <option key={index} value={assignment}>
                  {assignment}
                </option>
              ))
            ) : (
              <option disabled>No assignments available</option>
            )}
          </select>
        </div>

        {error && <div className="error-message">{error}</div>}

        <TableContainer component={Paper} className="fixed-table-container">
          <Table stickyHeader>
            <TableHead>
              <TableRow>
                <TableCell><strong>Assignment Name</strong></TableCell>
                <TableCell><strong>Submitted By (User ID)</strong></TableCell>
                <TableCell><strong>Time Submitted</strong></TableCell>
                <TableCell><strong>Assignment ID</strong></TableCell>
                <TableCell><strong>Video URL</strong></TableCell>
              </TableRow>
            </TableHead>
            <TableBody>
              {filteredVideos.slice(0, visibleCount).map((video) => (
                <TableRow key={video.videoId}>
                  <TableCell>{video.assign_name}</TableCell>
                  <TableCell>{video.user_id}</TableCell>
                  <TableCell>{new Date(video.upload_date).toLocaleString()}</TableCell>
                  <TableCell>{video.assignment_id}</TableCell>
                  <TableCell>
                    <Link 
                      to={`/watch-feedback/${encodeURIComponent(video.videoUrl)}`} // Use encodeURIComponent for safety
                      onClick={() => console.log(video.videoUrl)} // Log the video URL for debugging
                    >
                      Watch Video
                    </Link>
                  </TableCell>
                </TableRow>
              ))}
            </TableBody>
          </Table>
        </TableContainer>

        <button className="get-started-button" onClick={toggleShowMore}>
          {showMore ? 'Show Less' : 'Show More'}
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ListVideos;

the second one:
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Link, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';

const VideoFeedback = () => {
  const { videoUrl } = useParams(); // Get videoUrl from URL parameters
  const [mark, setMark] = useState('');
  const [comment, setComment] = useState('');

  const handleSubmitFeedback = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    try {
      const response = await axios.post('/api/marks/submit-feedback', {
        videoUrl, // Use videoUrl directly here
        mark,
        comment,
      });
      alert(response.data.message);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error submitting feedback:', error);
      alert('Failed to submit feedback. Please try again.');
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="page">
      <header>
        <div className="container">
          <h1 className="page-heading">Watch Video and Provide Feedback</h1>
          <ul className="linksList">
            <li><Link to="/" className="link">Landing Page</Link></li>
            <li><Link to="/list-videos" className="link">Back to Video List</Link></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </header>

      <div className="page-Container">
        {/* Video Player */}
        {videoUrl ? (
          <video width="640" height="360" controls autoPlay>
            <source src={decodeURIComponent(videoUrl)} type="video/mp4" />
            Your browser does not support the video tag.
          </video>
        ) : (
          <p>No video available to play.</p>
        )}

        {/* Feedback Form */}
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmitFeedback} className="feedback-form">
          <div className="form-group">
            <label htmlFor="mark">Mark:</label>
            <input
              type="number"
              id="mark"
              value={mark}
              onChange={(e) => setMark(e.target.value)}
              required
              min="0"
              max="100"
              placeholder="Enter mark out of 100"
            />
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label htmlFor="comment">Commentary Feedback:</label>
            <textarea
              id="comment"
              value={comment}
              onChange={(e) => setComment(e.target.value)}
              required
              placeholder="Enter your feedback here"
            ></textarea>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" className="feedback-Sub">Submit Feedback</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default VideoFeedback;

This is my app.js
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import LandingPage from './pages/LandingPage';
import LoginPage from './pages/LoginPage';
import UserAdminPage from './pages/UserAdminPage';
import ListAssignments from './pages/ListAssignments';
import CreateAssignment from './pages/CreateAssignment';
import ListVideos from './pages/ListVideos';
import VideoFeedback from './pages/VideoFeedback';
import StudentPage from './pages/studentPage';
import LecturerPage from './pages/lecturerPage';

import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<LandingPage />} />
        <Route path="/login" element={<LoginPage />} />
        <Route path="/user-admin" element={<UserAdminPage />} />
        <Route path="/list-assignments" element={<ListAssignments />} />
        <Route path="/create-assignment" element={<CreateAssignment />} />
        <Route path="/list-videos" element={<ListVideos />} />
        <Route path="/watch-feedback/:id" element={<VideoFeedback />} />
        <Route path="/user-student" element={<StudentPage />} />
        <Route path="/user-lecturer" element={<LecturerPage />} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );`enter code here`
};

export default App;


Please [edit] to include a complete [mcve] of the relevant code you are working with. We need to see your routes where you declare a route path with a videoUrl path parameter. Based on your links it looks like you have a "/watch-feedback/:id" route path somewhere. Are you trying to pass the video ID value?

No, I am trying to pass the videoUrl to the Watch Video page.

Ok, the route path parameter is named id. Destructure that from the route parameters. I suggest passing the video URL via the search params though.
